# CSS Crop Center & Scale

Tags: html, css

I want to make a site that works on any display size, and to do so I need a way to crop, center, and scale an image accordingly.

The image is 2560x735 and here is how it should react to different displays:

My current attempt is in this snippet:

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 735px;
  min-width: 980px;
  background-image: url('http://cl.ly/Z0O0/01940_morainelake_2560x1440.jpg');
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

2560x735

[image: 2560X735]

1920x735

[image: 1920x735]

980x735 —  This is the minimum width of the image

[image: 980x735]

375x735

This is the same image as before (980x735), but scaled to 100% of the display width. Media queries will probably be useful here.

[image: 375x735]

Comment: Nothing there, mate. But, looking at your source, you're not seeing a background image because your `div` height is set to `auto`, and with no content in the `div`, it's height is 0. The `background-image` property doesn't add height to your `div`.

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), before you ask a question. Posts without any code are 90% more likely to recieve downvotes and eventually they will be closed.

Comment: @JaydenIrwin - I [made a really basic example with media queries here](http://jsbin.com/busajo/1/edit?css,output), resize the output to see the different widths. Could be useful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you may be looking to use @media CSS at-rule ([review it on Mozilla Dev Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media)) if you want resizing to occur at specific dimensions. Other than that, just put

```
body {
    background: url('http://yourimage.com');
}
```

specify any other applicable properties you need, like `no-repeat`, et cetera

Look this over
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/22/simple-responsive-images-with-css-background-images/

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the image scales properly, the easiest way to do so is to use the `background-size: cover` property. It'll keep your background-image scaled as large as it can within the container.

Like I mentioned in my comment, you have to set a height for the container div - `auto` won't work because the `background-image` doesn't add any content to the div, so it's height will be 0 otherwise.

Here's what I would do:

**CSS**

```
html,body {        /* This ensures no white border around your page */
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
#container {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: url('your-image-url-here') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Here's a **[CodePen demo](http://codepen.io/bbennett/pen/RNRpMK)** showing a simple example.